# How can $(\Bbb Z_n, +_n)$ be a cyclic group with generator $1$ if we cant generate $0$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

I am currently taking an intro to group theory module and they mention that the following is a cyclic group:

$$(\Bbb Z_n, +_n),$$

where $\Bbb Z_n$ is the set of integers mod $n$ (i.e $0$ to $n-1$) and $+_n$ is addition mod $n$

Since for all $n, \Bbb Z_n = \langle1 \rangle_{z_n}$

But this generator will create the set:

$\{1,1,1+1,1+1+1,...\} = \{1,2,3,...\}$

Which is missing zero, even though $0\in Z_n$

Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: if you add $1$ $n$ times you get $0$.

Comment: @Onir I must have gotten confused (since this is my first time dealing with groups) so I forgot $1^0$ here isnt 1, can you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: sure thing ${}{}{}$

Comment: And when you consider generators you not only include positive multiples (in an additive notation) but also $0$-th and negative multiples. In this way the $1$ from $\mathbb{Z}$, generates $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$. In $(\mathbb{Z}_n, +_n)$ you can also generate $0\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ as $0\cdot 1$. This is, $1$ added to itself zero times.

Comment: As a rule, we say $g$ generates additive group $A$ if all elements $a\in A$ can be written as $a=ng$ for $n\in\mathbb Z.$ That includes negative $n.$ So $1$ is a generator foe $(\mathbb Z,+,0).$ In the case of finite groups, $n>0$ is all that is required since $mg=0$ for some $m>0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the group $\mathbb Z_n$ we have that $\underbrace{1+1+\dots +1}_\text{n times}$ is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

You have a confused definition of “generates.”

If $G$ is a group, and $g\in G,$ the subgroup of $G$ generated by $g,$ written $\langle g\rangle,$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ which contains $g.$

If $\mathcal S_g$ is the the collection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $g,$  then:

$$\langle g\rangle =\bigcap_{H\in \mathcal S_g} H.$$

It turns out you can write:

$$\langle g\rangle =\{g^n\mid n\in \mathbb Z\}.\tag 1$$

Note, we can have $n$ positive or negative or $0.$

In a lot of the teaching, $(1)$ is the **definition** of the subgroup generated by $g,$ and the “smallest subgroup” definition  is seen as a result of $(1).$

But the “smallest subgroup” definition generalizes more readily to other types of algebras, like semigroups and monoids.

When $G$ is additive $(1)$ is rewritten as:

$$\langle g\rangle =\{ng\mid n\in \mathbb Z\}.$$

Again, $n\leq 0$ is allowed.

We say $g$ generates $G$ if $\langle g\rangle =G.$

So, for example, $1$ is a generator for $(\mathbb Z,+).$

---

Then, of course, as others have pointed out, if $G$ is finite, we have that:

$$\langle g\rangle =\{g^n\mid n\in\mathbb Z^+\}.$$

In particular, we only need positive $n.$

---

Now, $g=1$ does not generate $G=(\mathbb Z,+)$ if we were talking about $G$ as only a semigroup. That’s because $(\mathbb Z^+,+)$ is a sub-semigroup of $G.$

But even with monoids (semigroups with an identity,) $\langle 1\rangle$ In $(\mathbb Z,+)$ includes $0,$ because a sub-monoid of a monoid must contain the identity.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are all correct, but in fact you don't need any generators at all to generate $0$. The subgroup generated by the empty subset of $G$ is $\{0\}$.

As Thomas Andrews pointed out, the formal definition of the subgroup a group $G$ generated by a subset $S$ of $G$ is the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ that contain $S$. So if we take $S$ to be the empty set, then all subgroups of $G$ contain $S$, and their intersection is the trivial subgroup of $G$, which is $\{0\}$ in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of $\Bbb Z_n$ can be seen as equivalence classes like so:

$$[x]_n=\{y\in \Bbb Z: n\mid y-x\}.$$

The addition is given by

$$[a]_n+_n[b]_n=[a+b]_n.$$

(Can you show that this is well-defined?)

Consider

$$\begin{align}
\underbrace{[1]_n+_n\dots+_n[1]_n}_{n\text{ times}}&=\left[\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_{n\text{ times}}\right]_n\\
&=[n]_n\\
&=\{m\in\Bbb Z: n\mid m-n\}\\
&=\{m\in\Bbb Z: n\mid m\}\\
&=\{m\in\Bbb Z: n\mid m-0\}\\
&=[0]_n.
\end{align}$$